# Сжатие файла при сохранении

Tags: c#, selenium

Делаю с помощью Selenium скриншот, обрезаю его и хочу сохранить со сжатием, но оно не происходит( - в чём загвоздка ?

Так проверял оригинал:

```
screenshot2.Save(String.Format(@"C:\SeleniumScreenshots\" + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg));
```

А так пытался сжать:

```
screenshot2.Save(String.Format(@"C:\SeleniumScreenshots\" + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg, new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 25L)));
```

И каждый раз файлы одного и того же размера

Comment: Jpeg - это уже сжатие с потерями.

Comment: @ГеннадийП но судя по этому я могу регулировать ещё и % сжатия, но никак не могу применить(
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level

Comment: попробуйте как в примере myEncoderParameters вынести, скорее всего в этом проблема